# celery logging not showing in django application inside docker shell

Tags: python, django, celery

from logging import error

```
@app.task
def partial_bid_created_event(event):
    event_time = get_event_time()

    print('wrong function')
    a = getWrongfunc()
    # here it should throw error because that function is not exist.
```

error showing in my docker django shell .

```
antiquely  | Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
antiquely  | Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
watcher    | wrong function
watcher exited with code 1
watcher    | Monitoring 1 contracts using %s rinkeby.infura.io
watcher    | subscription id: %s 0x1feed3405f0f0680df9c9684957ad03d
```

It is just showing `exited with code 1`
but i am expecting exact error for logging
Is it because of celery async task ?

How to get exception on this error .

Please take a look

Comment: Whats the status in celery backend db. Check the error in "result" column/key in respective celery table/collection. (Key, collection in case u are using mongodb as celery backend)

Comment: Can you post more logs? The reason your watcher container exited should be printed as well.

Comment: It s not printing. That is the issue. It is only showng exited with code 0